# Why does jobOperator.startNextInstance does not accept parameters?

Tags: spring, spring-batch, jsr352

I have a job which accepts parameters `x=y` and I have scheduled to run every 10 seconds. Here's how I start it:

```
final JobExecution previousExecution = jobRepository.getLastJobExecution(jobId, jobParameters);
if (previousExecution != null && previousExecution.getStartTime() != null) {
    return jobOperator.startNextInstance(jobId);
} else {
    return jobOperator.start(jobId, PropertiesConverter.propertiesToString(jobParametersConverter.getProperties(jobParameters)));
}
```

The first time I start the job, it goes in the `else` clause and it starts successfully. After 10 seconds it goes inside the `if` clause and it starts successfully too. Then I manually run the job (via REST API) but this time with parameters `x=z` and it runs it successfully too. Then 10 seconds pass and the job is about to be start again. Now `jobRepository.getLastJobExecution` returns the correct `x=y` execution, but guess what - `jobOperator.startNextInstance` does not care about your parameters - it only accepts `jobId`. And inside it loads the wrong `x=z` instance and starts running the job with `x=z` from now on until forever every 10 seconds.

My question is - why is the `startNextInstance` not accept the jobParameters? I want to start a nextInstance for given job parameters, why is it not allowed?

Answer (score 1):

`JobOperator`, per the documentation is a low level interface and really isn't the ideal way to launch Spring Batch Jobs.  The `JobLauncher` is really the right way to launch jobs in Spring Batch and does accept parameters.

Comment: Hmmm.. `JobOperator` internally calls `JobLauncher` - perhaps that's why I thought the `JobLauncher` is the low-level one.

Comment: I don't have the full history on why the `JobOperator` was created, but most Spring components that launch jobs use the `JobLauncher`.  For example, in Spring Boot, jobs are launched via the `JobLauncherCommandLineRunner`.